# parameters do not show correctly

Tags: dictionary, url, intellij-idea, post, key-value

Kotlin can`t recognize values for parameters like merchant_id , amount , description , callback_uri.

> I tried to fill all keys by proper values but I got this error :
>
> > {"data":[],"errors":{"code":-9,"message":"The input params invalid, validation error.","validations":[{"merchant_id":"The merchant id field is required."},{"amount":"The amount field is required."},{"callback_url":"The callback url field is required."},{"description":"The description field is required."}]}}
>
> **here is my code :**

> ```
> import java.net.HttpURLConnection
> import java.net.URL
>
> fun main() {
>     val url = URL("https://api.zarinpal.com/pg/v4/payment/request.json")
>     val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
>     connection.requestMethod = "POST"
>     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
>     connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
>     connection.doOutput = true
>
>     val postData : String = """
>         {
>            
>           "amount": 1100,
>           "callback_url": "https://ali568865.ir/",
>           "merchant_id": "1344b5d4-0048-11e8-94db-005056a205be",
>           "back_uri": "Transaction description.",
>           "metadata": {
>             "mobile": "09106869409",
>             "email": "info.test@gmail.com",
>             "card_pan": "5022291083818920",
>           }
>         }
>     
>     """.trimIndent()
>
>     connection.outputStream.use { outputStream ->
>         outputStream.write(postData.toByteArray())
>     }
>
>     val responseCode = connection.responseCode
>     if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
>         val response = connection.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
>         println(response)
>     } else {
>         println("Failed to make the request. Response code: $responseCode")
>     }
>
>     connection.disconnect()
> }
> ```

Comment: {
    "data": {
        "code": 100,
        "message": "Success",
        "authority": "A00000000000000000000000000217885159",
        "fee_type": "Merchant",
        "fee": 100
    },
    "errors": []
}

Comment: that is the form of correct answer in run window of IntelliJ idea

Comment: but my answer is different as I post it up.